# Query function with two tabs in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a much larger version of the following tables across two sheets (Cat1, Cat2, respectively)

[screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi5yI.png)
I'd like to get to an output like the following:

| City | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Boston | Tea |
| Boston | Beer |
| Boston | Burger |

Where when the matrix = Ready, it shows me city and the category that is ready. I've never used query before, and what I have tried hasn't worked, but this seems like the right tool for the job. Any help is appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell `A1` on a new sheet (delete everything below):

```
=arrayformula({"City","Category";query(split(flatten({'Cat1'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat1'!B2:D="Ready",'Cat1'!B1:D1,);'Cat2'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat2'!B2:D="Ready",'Cat2'!B1:D1,)}),char(9999)),"where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2",0)})
```

[image]

With 12 columns:

```
=arrayformula({"City","Category";query(split(flatten({'Cat1'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat1'!B2:M="Ready",'Cat1'!B1:M1,);'Cat2'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat2'!B2:M="Ready",'Cat2'!B1:M1,)}),char(9999)),"where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2",0)})
```

[image]

[image: 'Cat1' sheet]

[image: 'Cat2' sheet]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Much appreciated. Its spinning off an array error. "in Array_Literal, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"

Comment: Are you able to share screen grabs or the sheet? It sounds like the query hasn't come back with the desired output (perhaps due to your live data). You could try removing `"City","Category";` and see what columns result, and what error message you get.

Comment: I've re-upped it with the screen grabs.  That's the structure of the data.  There are ~170 cities on both tabs, and there are 12 categories on each

Comment: The range is now different. It goes to G. Try: `=arrayformula({"City","Category";query(split(flatten({'Cat1'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat1'!B2:G="Ready",'Cat1'!B1:G1,);'Cat2'!A2:A&char(9999)&if('Cat2'!B2:G="Ready",'Cat2'!B1:G1,)}),char(9999)),"where Col2 is not null order by Col1,Col2",0)})`

Comment: For 12 columns, change the range from `G` to `M` - in 4 places.

Comment: Same error I'm afraid.  It's not the range

Comment: Can you share the sheet or show the adapted formula?